# Regex RE: All but not this pattern

Tags: python, regex

quick question...
I need a regex that matches a particular letter in a code unless it is contained in a certain pattern.

I want something that matches N followed or preceded by anything aslong as it isn't preceded IMMEDIATELY by C(=O).

Example:

```
C(=O)N
```

Should not match

```
C(=O)CN
```

Should match

But it doesn't need an anchor because:

```
C(=O)NCCCN
```

Should match because of the N at the end

So far i have this:

```
(?!C\(=O\)N$)[N]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a negative lookbehind:

```
(?<!C\(=O\))N
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nI7wO4/3)

The `N` will get matched only when not preceded immediately with a literal `C(=O)` sequence.

The `(?<!...)` is called a *negative lookahead*. It does not consume characters (does not move the regex index), but just checks if something is absent from the string *before* the current position. If the text is matched, the match is failed (there is no match). See [**Lookarounds**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for more details.

[In Python](https://ideone.com/UtXpRb): `r'(?<!C\(=O\))N'`:

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'(?<!C\(=O\))N')
strs = ["C(=O)N", "C(=O)CN", "C(=O)NCCCN"]
print([x for x in strs if p.search(x)])
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain the < symbol to me?

Comment: The `(?<!...)` is called a *negative lookahead*. It does not consume characters (does not move the regex index), but just checks if something is absent from the string *before* the current position. If the text is matched, the match is failed (there is no match). See [**Lookarounds**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for more details.

Comment: If I wanted to make it so it was before and after the N i would use:  `(?<!C\(=O\))N(?!C\(=O\))` but what if i wanted to add another condition that said AND also `N` is not in `C(N)=O`?

Comment: `N` not in `C(N)=O` - it does not seem that you can easily solve this with two lookarounds ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/xQ2fL6/1)). Maybe you should just match and capture this with `(C\(N\)=O)` and then use non-regex means to manipulate it? It depends on what you are doing of course (replacing?).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109577/discussion-between-ben-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 2):

Use a negative look-behind instead:

```
(?<!C\(=O\))N
```

[See this regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/pP5gR5/1).

Regards.